# iOS using pod install as Pre-action run script for building the project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I added the Pods/* to the .gitignore, I have the Podfile.lock under the source control.

While creating a new branch, I have to run the `pod install`. As I don't have the pods installed for the new branch.

I tried adding the Pre-Action Run Script. The Pre-Action Run Script will do the following

1. Move to the Project Directory
2. Run the `pod install`.

I am able to see all the pods installed.

However if I try to build, XCode throws error saying that there is `no such module in the source files`.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Can you elaborate? CocoaPods already has a build phase that runs before compilation called "Check Pods Manifest.lock". Are you running your script before or after this one?

Comment: Who is doing the building?  You manually (via a "Build"/"Run"/"Archive" within Xcode)?  Or some CI / Continuous Integration scheme, like Jenkins or Travis? Also, what ***thing*** is open within Xcode where you see these build phases?  A project or a workspace?

Comment: I am trying to Run the project, maybe I was doing at a wrong place. It should been associated with the Build Pre-Action.